# How to serve an static image using angular and Spring MVC?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Now I created file upload component and saved the uploaded file in physical path in hard desk. So, now how to use this relative path when I want to serve this image in angular when I open image in new tab with right click it should be converted to  localhost/port-number/image-path?

Using configurations in application properties I am trying to use external URL in configuration but I do not know what should I set in this URL What changes I need to do to serve an image.

Comment: Here http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-uploadget-multipartfile-tofrom-spring-boot-server you can find how java.nio.file used to create directory as well getting all files under directory and display it in UI using anugular & sprint-boot

Answer (score 0):

If the hard disk path is inside the document root of the webserver you can access it directly using the url relative to the document root.

Example:
The document root in the hard disk is `/var/www/examplesite` and you have uploaded the file `theimage.jpg` into `/var/www/examplesite/uploads`, then you access the image as `http://example.com/uploads/theimage.jpg`

If you have uploaded the file outside of the document root then you need to implement a mechanism to read the file from its location and serve it from the application server or servlet container.

Checkout this tutorial, it shows you how to forward the request to a resource inside the WEB-INF folder using Spring MVC.

[Returning Image/Media Data with Spring MVC by baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data)

Comment: yes i just uploaded files and saved it in physical path in hard desk outside the project root ... and now want to serve those files inside project

Comment: I added a tutorial where you have the steps to forward the response to an image resource in the WEB-INF folder. I guess it should work for any other location on the server, but WEB-INF is the place to put non-public resources.

Comment: Use java.nio.file for accessing file directory checkout this link 
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/file-nio/path/java-nio-file-path-example/

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) was designed to do just this.  With Spring Content FS (i.e. Spring Content for the file-system) you can create a REST service that supports CRUD operations on content by defining a single interface.

To do this, add the following Spring Content dependencies to your project (assuming maven):-

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Standard Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Content -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In your Spring Boot Application class, create a ImageStore.  This instructs Spring Content to inject a REST service for this interface, saving you from having to write any this code yourself (including the upload code):-

```
    @SpringBootApplication 
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {        
           SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);  
        }

        @StoreRestResource(path="images")   
        public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {} 
    }
```

NB: and by the way this service support video streaming too!

Please note that by default Spring Content FS will create a store uploaded images under java.io.tmpdir and you'll get a new root every time you start the application.  So you will also need to set the SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT environment variable to give you application a stable root for your images".

Having done this you will be able to POST (create), GET (read), PUT (update) and DELETE (delete) to the URI "/images" with an arbitrary path like so:-

> /images/some/path/myimage.jpeg

For example, a POST to this URL will store the image to SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT/some/path/myimage.jpeg.  A GET will retrieve it again and so on.